# Change current internet connection interface

Tags: networking, debian, nat

I am at a dorm, where the internet is shut down at 11.30PM but I own a Vodafone dongle and I would like to automate the NAT setup, so that at 11.30pm, sakis3g is invoked to connect ppp0 to the internet and wlan0 is replaced by ppp0 for the device's internet, and the nat too.

Setting up the nat is not a problem, but just at this moment, I have the wlan and the 3g dongle (wlan0, ppp0) plugged in at the same time. Whenever I request my external IP using curl, it returns the dongle's IP.

How do I change my current internet connection? From OS X I have seen the "prefered interface" listing, where you can prioritize the various interfaces.

I am on a Raspberry Pi, Raspbian Wheezy.

Kind regards, Ingwie

Comment: Do you want it to automatically change over whenever wlan0 is down, or do you just want something that can be automated via cronjob?

Comment: I will be automating the switching via a cronjob. What I need is just the very basic command(s) to tell linux thru which iface it should connect to the internet...the rest I can figure out myself, but I didnt find anything on google for that issue.

Comment: Hm. Does `dhclient wlan0` turn the wifi into the preferred interface?

Comment: Also, what's the Default Route listed when you enter `sudo ./sakis3g connect info`?

Comment: @cpast: the said command doesnt do anything, it only says that a file exists. The second command returns: http://pastebin.com/apDHcpHT (although its german you most probably will understand it)